# AWS S3 data format in files for AWS Athena queries

Tags: json, csv, http, parquet, amazon-athena

I would like to store http request payload in AWS S3 and do queries on these data by using AWS Athena. What format of data in files, recommand in this case to store in S3?

Choices are: JSON, CSV, TSV, Textfiles, Apache ORC, Apache Parquet, Compressed data.

Currently I am consider these 3 aspects: time for serialization/de-serialization, Query speed, space.

Any links might be helpful are welcomed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Athena currently supports following file formats.

- Avro
- CloudTrail
- CSV (OpenCSVSerDe)
- TSV
- Parquet Serde
- ORC
- JSON
- Apache Web Server logs (RegexSerDe)
- Custom Delimiters

In order to use these formats you must specify a serializer-deserializer class (SerDe) so that Athena knows the format of the table.

To improve Athena query performance the significant factor is partitioning your data. By partitioning your data, you can restrict the amount of data scanned by each query, thus improving performance and reducing cost.

For more information, check [Athena partitioning](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html) and supported [file formats](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/supported-formats.html).

Answer (score 0):

For serialization and query performance as well as space, Apache Parquet and ORC will be the best choice. They both are columnar data formats using various encoding and compression techniques to optimize size and query performance at the same time.

The choice between ORC and Parquet is mostly up to the tools you plan to use. While Parquet is the more widespread one, some tools perform better with ORC.

There is one constraint in using these formats: they are  optimized for batch workloads. This means that you should also need to write them in batches.